# CSS inset shadow not working, creating vertical line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to create an inset shadow in a div upon hovering over it, but the only thing that shows up is a white vertical bar on the left side of the div. I am working in Chrome 36.0.1985.143. If I replace the inset shadow with a normal one, it works perfectly.

HTML:

```
<div id="innerContent">
    <div id="digSynth" class="selection">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="Digital Synthesizer/thumbnail.png">
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <span class="infoItem">Control the pitch of a speaker by adjusting the light level</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ledDom" class="selection">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //highlight on hover mechanism
    $(".selection").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0.8em 0em white");
    });
    $(".selection").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "");
    });

});
```

It's  basically two small divs side by side inside a larger div. There is an img inside the small div on the left. All three divs are position: absolute. The white bar appears on the inside of the large div, and stays as long as I keep the mouse hovered over the large div.

Comment: How about a jsFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the (recomended) css syntax for box-shadows is as follows:

```
box-shadow: (the extra-options can be here too but it's considered a bad practice so don't do that) [x-offset y-offset blur] extra-options
```

The [things between brackets] must go in that order(they must be next to each other too)

```
.selection {
    transition:box-shadow 0.3s;
}
.selection:hover {
    box-shadow:.8em .8em 1.6em red inset;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rc25wth/)